# Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, graph, pathfinding

Assuming everything else works as expected, is the following a correct - but not the most efficient way - of implementing Dijkstra algorithm? Because I have tested it on several examples and it gives correct result. But I can't imagine Dijkstra is *that* simple.

```
  public static void FindShortestPath(Node source, Directed graph)
    {
        if(source==null)
        {
            System.err.println("Source doesn't exist.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
       source.setCost(0); // all nodes are initialized with cost=Double.Max_VALUE when first created.
       PriorityQueue<Node> pq=new PriorityQueue<>(); // Node implements comparable according to cost
       for(Node node:graph.getAdj().keySet()) // get all nodes 
          pq.add(node); 
        while(!pq.isEmpty()) 
        {
            Node u=pq.poll(); // the minimum
            List<Node> neighbours=graph.getAdj().get(u); // get the minimum direct successors
            for(Node v:neighbours) 
            { 
                if(v.getCost()>(u.getCost()+(graph.getCost(u, v)))) // if there is a cheaper one
                {
                    v.setCost(u.getCost()+graph.getCost(u, v)); // change its cost
                    pq.remove(v);  //remove it
                    pq.add(v);  // add it again
                } 
            }
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question - yes, this is a correct solution (the algorithm is pretty simple), and yes, it is not the most efficient one.

The efficiency depends on the implementation of the priority queue. In your case, I assume this is `PriorityQueue` provided in `java.util`. The more efficient way uses what is called a [Fibonacci Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap). Unfortunately, there is no implementation available in `java.util`, but there are plenty of implementations online (like [this one](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=fibonacci-heap)). You can test your solution using one of them.

---

I will also suggest a couple of things you could implement to improve readability of your code.

---

### Naming

In Java, methods should start with a lowercase character, unlike classes. So it is best practice to name your method `findShortestPath`.

Also, while frequent in mathematical notation, variable names like `u` and `v` can be confusing. These are `Node`s in your case, so you can name them accordingly: `currentNode`, `neighbourNode`, or at least just `current` and `neighbour`.

---

### Formatting

One of your loops contains only one statement, but I would *strongly suggest* adding brackets anyway or extracting the whole thing to a separate method (see below).

Additionally, consider:

`for(Node v:neighbours)`

`for(Node v : neighbours)`

It's a small thing, but most code formatters will do it this way, and it is easier to read.

The same goes for:

`Node u=pq.poll();`

`Node u = pq.poll();`

The same applies to mathematical operations, like:

`v.getCost() > (u.getCost() + (graph.getCost(u, v))`

If you are using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA, there are features that format your code automatically.

### Comments and methods

Comments are good if you are writing complex code that could be hard to understand without them. That's not the case here. Compare:

```
if(v.getCost()>(u.getCost()+(graph.getCost(u, v)))){ // if there is a cheaper one
    // do stuff
}
```

with

```
if(thereIsACheaperOne(u,v)){
    // do stuff
}

private boolean thereIsACheaperOne(Node u, Node v){
   return v.getCost()>(u.getCost()+(graph.getCost(u, v)))
}
```

When the method names you are using are meaningful, there is no need to comment code - it comments itself. If you extract a lot of statements like this, reading the algorithm becomes **really easy**. It becomes a short list of easy to understand calls, instead of lots of mathematical operations here and there.

And if you are unsure about what a certain step does, you can just read one specific method body.

A good rule for naming the method could be what I just done - just name the method just like you would phrase the comment.

In general, one method should be doing one thing and one thing only.

```
pq.remove(v);  //remove it
pq.add(v);  // add it again
```

Comments like these are pretty much useless. Anyone with a minimum knowledge about programming will know what this code does. These comments make the code messy.

---

### And more...

In your code, you use `graph.getAdj()` twice. Now, what will happen, if something (e.g. another thread) changes the `graph` after you added all your nodes, but before you started calculating distances? I suggest that you create a local final variable in your method:

`final <WhateverTypeItIs> adjacencyStructure = graph.getAdj()`

This way, you are sure that you are working on the same copy of the adjacency structure (be it a list, or matrix) everywhere in your method.

You could also consider adding exception handling to your method instead of checking for `source == null`. And why are you only checking source? What happens if `graph` is null?

I would separate this into two parts: first, try to get all the variables needed and then call a separate method that is the algorithm itself. All this in a `try-catch` block. You could easily catch the `NullPointerException` and inform the user that either `source` or `graph` is not set up properly. Or, better, add a bit more logic to that to ensure which of these is not set up properly.

Comment: You should also point out there should be spaces around operators. I.e. `(x) + (y)` not `(x)+(y)`. This is common for code clarity.